# Remove duplicates and alert user with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am important data using a soap call, my problem is that under certain circumstances I may end up with duplicate data.

I can easily remove this data using
`WS.Range("A6:O200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(2)`

However Id like to alert the user when this happens via a MsgBox. Currently I am trying to get this working with some code adapted from another post on here.

```
Dim dict As Object

' Let Col be the column which warnDupes operates on.
Dim Col As String

Col = "B"

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

dupeRow = Range(Col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
For i = dupeRow To 1 Step -1
    If dict.Exists(UCase$(Range(Col & i).Value)) = True Then

    'range("Y" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    WS.Range("A6:O200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(2)

    'MsgBox ("Hmm...Seems to be a duplicate of " & Range(Col & i).Value & _
    " in Cell " & Col & i)

End If

dict.Add UCase$(Range(Col & i).Value), 1
Next

 MsgBox ("Duplicate unfullfilled requests where removed")
```

The problem is of course that this either displays the message for every duplicate value deleted in the loop or even if there are no duplicates (as it does now). Ideally what I want is the remove duplicates to run completely and then alert the user via a message.

Regards
Sam

Comment: You can set up Counter in String Form. Use it to concatenate in your loop instead of Msgbox. And after the loop ends you can print that concatenated Text as the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim dict As Object

' Let Col be the column which warnDupes operates on.
Dim Col As String
Dim bCount as Boolean

Col = "B"

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

dupeRow = Range(Col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error Resume Next
For i = dupeRow To 1 Step -1
    If dict.Exists(UCase$(Range(Col & i).Value)) = True Then

        'range("Y" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        WS.Range("A6:O200").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(2)

        bCount = True

        'MsgBox ("Hmm...Seems to be a duplicate of " & Range(Col & i).Value & _
        " in Cell " & Col & i)

    End If

    dict.Add UCase$(Range(Col & i).Value), 1
Next

If bCount Then
    MsgBox ("Duplicate unfullfilled requests where removed")
End If
```

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for this code. Something still isn't quite right though for me. Its always firing the message. by updating the code of the message box I can see its thinking that there is a duplicate value of 1234 in Cell B10. B10 happens to be my final row of data containing that value

Comment: I managed to solve this by setting my dupeRow to 6 (thats where my data starts). Thanks for your help